# Accounting for Empty String in Isogram javascript function

Tags: javascript

How do i make the regex below account for empty strings.

e.g isIsogram(" ").

Empty string should return false.

```js
function isIsogram(str){ 
  return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Here is the updated code using the suggested solutions 

`function isIsogram(str) {
  if (!str.trim()) return false;
  return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just check length before testing regex and return false if it has no length

```
return str.length ? !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str) : false
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if(str.length){
   return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str)
}else{
   return false
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but i haven't got past the assessment. I still get an error on submission. The length property is seen as an error on the solution

Comment: Not sure what that means exactly. Does the function return expected boolean or not? Your problem sounds unrelated to this function or the regex is not doing what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Trim the String to remove any trailing spaces and check if it is a falsy value (empty Strings are considered false).

```
if(!str.trim()){
 //empty String or String with only spaces
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/><button type="button" onClick="check()">Check</button>
<p/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
    function isIsogram(str){ 
      return str.trim()&&!/(\w).*\1/i.test(str);//not empty String and not matching the regular expression
    }
    function check(){
      document.getElementById("result").textContent = isIsogram(document.querySelector("input").value)?"String is an isogram.":"String is not an isogram.";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @hev1. The solution works on my console as expected but i get an error on submission. The solution is supposed to pass four tests but only three is passed at the moment.